# Simple VBA: Calling a Module from Command Button Produces ComboBox Object Required Error 424

Tags: vba, excel

I have a command button which is duplicated across 20 sheets, so I want to edit the code in 1 place (a module). My buttons are set up like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Main
End Sub
```

But when I click on my button, I get an object error 424 with ComboBox1:

```
Public Sub Main()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
sourceFolder = "C:\MyDirectory\" & Month(DateValue("01-" & ComboBox1.Value & "-1900")) & ". " & ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date) & "\"
```

Comment: You don't need to use `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` to set `ws` to `ActiveSheet`, it's enough to use `Set ws = ActiveSheet`. Even though, it's better to avoid using `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how can I resolve my combobox drama?

Comment: Did you try the solution I've provided ? Where is the code of `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click` located ? in the worksheet ? or module ?

Comment: yes, but i still get an error at the sourceFolder line when i debug

Comment: what value are you getting in `ComboBox1.Value` ?

Comment: The ComboBox also exists on every worksheet. It contains the 12 months of the year. The user selects the month, presses the command button, and the worksheet fetches data from external workbooks. The program works, but putting it into a module and calling it from the Sub of the buttons creates that object error. I think its the ComboBox causing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148638/discussion-between-sean-kelly-and-shai-rado).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to reference it as an object:

```
Combox1.Value
```

changed to:

```
ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value
```

Everything works and I can call this module from other worksheets/buttons

Comment: The reason for this is that `ComboBox` isn't something that *exists* inherently (on a UserForm, this would be different and you could directly refer to `Me.ComboBox1` or `ComboBox1`. On a worksheet, they're embedded OLE Objects, and you need to refer to them as you found out. BTW, if you use `Option Explicit` (and you should) at the top of all modules  the compiler alerts you to the fact that `ComboBox1` is not declared a variable. Since it's implicitly handled as an empty variant, then you will get the 424 error because you're trying to invoke a method/property (`.Value`) against a non-object